# "403 Forbidden - You don't have permission to access / on this server" - apache2 localhost on Linux Mint 17

Tags: linux-mint, apache-httpd

**Desired Behaviour**

To be able to access localhost in browser without getting 403 Forbidden message.

**Current Behaviour**

Navigating to localhost in browser returns:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

**Steps To Reproduce**

I set up a local server on `Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon` using these steps:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2 php5
$ sudo apt-get install php5-dev php5-cli
$ sudo apt-get install php-pear
$ pear version
// PEAR Version: 1.9.4
// PHP Version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5
// Zend Engine Version: 2.5.0
// Running on: Linux my-computer 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64

$ pecl version ## as above

$ sudo pecl install mongo ## this installs the mongo driver
```

At this point, I was prompted with something containing [no] and I pressed enter.

```
$ cd /etc/php5/apache2
$ sudo vi php.ini
```

At the end of the file I added:  `extension=mongo.so`

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

At the end of this process, yesterday, I could access localhost successfully.

Today, I am getting the 403 error when navigating to localhost.

**Troubleshooting**

*Apache Status*

```
me@my-computer ~ $ /etc/init.d/apache2 status
 * apache2 is running
```

*Permissions*

**/var**

```
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  4096 Nov 23 08:58 var
```

**/var/www**

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Nov 23 08:58 www
```

**/var/www/html**

```
drwx------ 8 me me 4096 Nov 22 01:07 html
```

**/var/www/html/index.html**

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  11510 Nov 23 08:59 index.html
```

Answer (score 9):

Looking at the permissions of `/var/www/html` showed me that only user `root` had Read Write Execute permissions.  As I was using the browser just as a standard user and not getting access, I assumed that 'Other' needed some permissions, so I did this:

```
sudo chmod 755 html -R
```

And the new permissions are now:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 me me 4096 Nov 23 22:59 html
```

Now I can access localhost in a browser.

I found this video on `"Users, Groups and Permissions in Linux"` very helpful:

http://youtu.be/zRw0SKaXSfI

Comment: That sounds exactly right. Thanks for taking the time to post it as an answer!

Comment: Thank you for assisting in clarifying my information sources!

Answer (score 0):

You shoud give apache execute/read access. The way @user1063287 said is good but may have security issues, giving access to other.
I think this way is better:

1) make apache owner of your site root:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data ROOT_OF_SITE
```

2) give it full access

```
chmod -R 700 ROOT_OF_SITE
```